# Is it okay to use jQuery in React just for Bootstrap's dropdown?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

In general people say it is bad practice to use jQuery at all inside a React app, since React assumes that it is the only thing manipulating the DOM. I'm wondering if there are any potential problems from using jQuery in isolated cases for convenience. For example, in Bootstrap's dropdown components. It seems the best alternative is to port everything over to React-bootstrap, which in my experience is much more annoying to customize.

Comment: A dropdown component is fairly simple to build on your own, and there's a ton of open source dropdown components for react out there beside the React-Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do that, you will have 2 different systems for updating your DOM. How will you keep them coordinated? If you don't have a plan, don't do this.

I would suggest wrapping React-bootstrap components inside your own components. When you need to heavily customize something, you will then have the option of dropping Bootstrap entirely and creating your own component from scratch. This isn't a huge lift.

You will have much more fun creating a React component from the ground up, than trying to troubleshoot issues caused by sneaking direct DOM manipulation into your React app.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that makes sense. To clarify: there are no issues with using strictly Bootstrap CSS (without jQuery), and writing the dynamic parts myself in React right?

Comment: Hmm, that's kind of a separate question. Bootstrap CSS doesn't make React break in any way. If you were to, say, componentize your CSS, the Bootstrap stuff would make that harder. And you probably want to make sure your Boostrap CSS gets executed (in the browser) before your site's CSS, so it will lose specificity ties to your custom code.